# Decision Tree Execution

Tags: java, binary-tree

I am developing a survey using a binary decision tree. The user is given a question that they answer "yes" or "no" to and the answer determines what question is asked next.

My problem is the code is only working to the left, meaning that the user is only allowed to answer no for the code to work properly. If the user gives the answer yes, then a NullPointerException gets thrown. Is it something that I am doing wrong

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class MusicGenreExpert {
    private static LinkedBinaryTree<String> tree;
    static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    public MusicGenreExpert() throws ElementNotFoundException
    {
        String e1 = "Are you eco-friendly?";
        String e2 = "Do you consider yourself to be outgoing?";
        String e3 = "Do you consider yourself to be an introvert?";
        String e4 = "On an average day, do you think that you approach and solve" +
                     "problems differently than others?";
        String e5 = "Are you often uneasy (nervous)?";
        String e6 = "If the person in front of you dropped money without knowing," +
        "would you pick it up and keep it?";
        String e7 = "Is gentle a good word that describes you?";
        String e8 = "Do you often worry about what other people may think?";
        String e9 = "Do you think highly of yourself, with little to no care of" +
                      "what others may think?";
        String e10 = "Are you happy with the accomplishments you've had in life" +
                      "thus far?";
        String e11 = "Would you consider yourself to be old fashion?";
        String e12 = "Do you put your all in everything that you do?";
        String e13 = "Is your idea of an epic night going to a rave with thousands" +
                     "of people?";
        String e14 = "Do you believe that Bob Marley is one of the greatest artist" + 
                     "of all time?";
        String e15 = "Would you call yourself an extravert?";
        String e16 = "Do you know remember when you fell in love with" +
                     "Hip Hop?";
        String e17 = "You are the music genre classical. You are a creative introvert"+
        "with a good sense of self esteem. You are at ease with yourself as well as"+
        "the world around you.";
        String e18 = "The indie and punk music genre best fits you. You are an intellectual" +
        "and creative introvert. You prefer not to work as hard as others and are less gentle." +
        "Your self esteem is a constant battle.";
        String e19 = "Rock/Heavy Metal best describes you. You are a creative and gentle" +
        "introvert with a constant battle with self esteem. However you are no stranger to" +
        "hard work.";
        String e20 = "You are a high self esteem, honest and convetional" +
        "introvert. The Pop culture is who you are inside. You may lack in creativity," +
        "but you make up for in hard work.";
        String e21 = " You remember the exact day you fell in love with Hip Hop." +
        "\n With your high self esteem and outgoing personality, you are sure to be" +
        "\n the life of the party. However, you could be more eco friendly and less" +
        " aggressive.";
        String e22 = "You are jazz, blues, and soul. You are a lot more extraverted" +
        "than others. Your at ease personality, high self esteem, and creativity" +
        "makes you the person that eveyone wants to know.";
        String e23 = "The electronic/dance genre describes exactly who you are." +
        "Assertive, outgoing, creative, yet aggressive gives everyone that comes" +
        "in contact with you something to love. You aren't as kind as others, but" +
        "hey, they love you anyway.";
        String e24 = "Music is suppose to tell a story, and country music does" +
        "just that. You are hardworking, conventional and outgoing. Oh and contrary" +
        "to what others may believe your emotional stability is just fine.";
        String e25 = "There is no other genre better to describe you than Reggae." +
        "You are a creative outgoing individual, with high self esteem. Where you" +
        "lack in hardwork you make up for in your kind and generous ways.";

        LinkedBinaryTree<String> n2, n3, n4, n5, n6, n7, n8, n9, n10, n11, n12, n13, n14,
        n15, n16, n17, n18, n19, n20, n21, n22, n23, n24, n25, n26, n27, n28, n29, n30,
        n31, n32, n33, n34, n35, n36, n37, n38, n39, n40, n41, n42, n43, n44, n45, n46,
        n47, n48, n49, n50, n51, n52, n53;

        n50 = new LinkedBinaryTree<String> (e16);
        n51 = new LinkedBinaryTree<String> (e17);
        n33 = new LinkedBinaryTree<String> (e8, n50, n51);

        n52 = new LinkedBinaryTree<String> (e16);
        n53 = new LinkedBinaryTree<String> (e18);
        n49 = new LinkedBinaryTree<String> (e8, n52, n53);

        n32 = new LinkedBinaryTree<String> (e21);
        n16 = new LinkedBinaryTree<String> (e15, n32, n33);

        n34 = new LinkedBinaryTree<String> (e17);
        n35 = new LinkedBinaryTree<String> (e18);
        n18 = new LinkedBinaryTree<String> (e7, n34, n35);

        n36 = new LinkedBinaryTree<String> (e18);
        n37 = new LinkedBinaryTree<String> (e19);
        n19 = new LinkedBinaryTree<String> (e12, n36, n37);

        n38 = new LinkedBinaryTree<String> (e16);
        n39 = new LinkedBinaryTree<String> (e20);
        n23 = new LinkedBinaryTree<String> (e16, n38, n39);

        n40 = new LinkedBinaryTree<String> (e21);
        n41 = new LinkedBinaryTree<String> (e23);
        n25 = new LinkedBinaryTree<String> (e8, n40, n41);

        n42 = new LinkedBinaryTree<String> (e22);
        n43 = new LinkedBinaryTree<String> (e20);
        n26 = new LinkedBinaryTree<String> (e16, n42, n43);

        n44 = new LinkedBinaryTree<String> (e23);
        n45 = new LinkedBinaryTree<String> (e19);
        n27 = new LinkedBinaryTree<String> (e6, n44, n45);

        n46 = new LinkedBinaryTree<String> (e17);
        n47 = new LinkedBinaryTree<String> (e24);
        n28 = new LinkedBinaryTree<String> (e14, n46, n47);

        n48 = new LinkedBinaryTree<String> (e17);
        n30 = new LinkedBinaryTree<String> (e7, n48, n49);

        n17 = new LinkedBinaryTree<String> (e18);
        n8 = new LinkedBinaryTree<String> (e7, n16, n17);

        n9 = new LinkedBinaryTree<String> (e9, n18, n19);

        n20 = new LinkedBinaryTree<String> (e17);
        n21 = new LinkedBinaryTree<String> (e18);
        n10 = new LinkedBinaryTree<String> (e7, n20, n21);

        n22 = new LinkedBinaryTree<String> (e19);
        n11 = new LinkedBinaryTree<String> (e5, n22, n23);

        n24 = new LinkedBinaryTree<String> (e19);
        n12 = new LinkedBinaryTree<String> (e10, n24, n25);

        n13 = new LinkedBinaryTree<String> (e11, n26, n27);

        n29 = new LinkedBinaryTree<String> (e19);
        n14 = new LinkedBinaryTree<String> (e12, n28, n29);

        n31 = new LinkedBinaryTree<String> (e22);
        n15 = new LinkedBinaryTree<String> (e13, n30, n31);

        n4 = new LinkedBinaryTree<String> (e6, n8, n9);
        n5 = new LinkedBinaryTree<String> (e9, n10, n11);

        n6 = new LinkedBinaryTree<String> (e4, n12, n13);
        n7 = new LinkedBinaryTree<String> (e3, n14, n15);

        n2 = new LinkedBinaryTree<String> (e2, n4, n5);
        n3 = new LinkedBinaryTree<String> (e3, n6, n7);

        tree = new LinkedBinaryTree<String> (e1, n2, n3);
    }

    public static void diagnose(){
        BinaryTree<String> current = tree;

        System.out.println("                        What music genre are you?       ");
        while(current.size() > 1)
        {
            System.out.println (current.getRootElement());
            if (scan.nextLine().equalsIgnoreCase("N"))
                current = current.getLeft();
            else
                current =  current.getRight();  
        }

        System.out.println (current.getRootElement());          
    }
```

}

Here is the LinkedBinaryTree which implements BinaryTree:

```
import java.util.Iterator;

public class LinkedBinaryTree<T> implements BinaryTree<T>
{
   protected BTNode<T> root;

   public LinkedBinaryTree(){
    root = null; 
 }

  public LinkedBinaryTree (T element)
  {
     root = new BTNode<T>(element);
  }

  public LinkedBinaryTree (T element, LinkedBinaryTree<T> left,
          LinkedBinaryTree<T> right)
       {
          root = new BTNode<T>(element);
          root.setLeft(left.root);
          root.setRight(right.root);
       }

   public T getRootElement()
   {
      if (root == null)
      throw new EmptyCollectionException ("Get root operation "
        + "failed. The tree is empty.");

      return root.getElement();
   }

   public LinkedBinaryTree<T> getLeft()
   {
      if (root == null)
      throw new EmptyCollectionException ("Get left operation "
        + "failed. The tree is empty.");

      LinkedBinaryTree<T> result = new LinkedBinaryTree<T>();
      result.root = root.getLeft();

       return result;
    }

    public T find (T target)
   {
      BTNode<T> node = null;

      if (root != null)
      node = root.find(target);

      if (node == null)
      throw new ElementNotFoundException("Find operation failed. "
        + "No such element in tree.");

      return node.getElement();
    }

    public int size()
   {
      int result = 0;

      if (root != null)
     result = root.count();

      return result;
   }

   public Iterator<T> iterator() 
   {
    return new ArrayIterator<T>();
    }

  public int height()
   {
     int result = 0;

     if (root == null)
      return result;

     if (root != null)
     result = root.height();  
     return result; 
  }

public BinaryTree<T> getRight() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
return null;
}

public boolean contains(T target) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return false;
}

 public boolean isEmpty() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return false;
  }

}
```

Comment: "gives you an error" - You don't specify the error given to you. Also, you should make a smaller example to help diagnose your issue.

Comment: It's in the evaluate and diagnose methods, when the user hits y to answer the question, it doesn't execute to the next question. Instead it bring me back to the while(current.size) statement with a nullexception error. If the user continues to hit no the program executes, it's when they hit yes that the error comes up

Comment: Where does class `LinkedBinaryTree` come from?

Comment: LinkedBinaryTree is used to create the decision tree. It links the tree nodes together

Comment: He didn't ask you, what `LinkedBinaryTree` does, but _where_ it comes from.

Comment: It is just being used as an implementation for the decision tree. If this isn't answering your question forgive me I'm a little confused as to what you're asking.

Comment: @K.dot people won't just run and run and debug your code until it gives perfect results... We don't even know what's supposed to happen; let alone which errors are semi-expected and which ones are just plain weird.

Have you tried running the code for 5 minutes under the debugger?

Comment: @Shark that's not what I'm expecting I really just wanted insight on where it was that I went wrong. I am still learning programming (have only taken two classes) so I'm still fairly new. I know that there is something wrong just don't know what. The program is suppose to ask a series of yes or no questions, the questions change according to the answer given. It's like a survey, then the result is given.

Comment: Along with the existing answer, (which honestly surprises me that it is so obvious), it should be noted in your `getLeft` method for the tree, you don't need to make any intermediate `result` variable; you can just do `return root.getLeft();` Same for most of the other methods, really.

Answer (score 0):

Now that you've provided the source of `LinkedBinaryTree`, the problem is clear.  The only time `getRight()` is called is when you answer `Y` or yes to one of the decisions, which executes this piece of code:

```
public BinaryTree<T> getRight() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return null;
}
```

Since it's returning `null`, the next time you try to dereference `current` -- which happens in the code `while(current.size() > 1)` -- it causes a `NullPointerException`.

The `getRight()` method needs to be implemented similar to `getLeft()`.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me, I have been going at this for days and didn't realize that something as simple as that was what my problem was.